# Access SASS variable in function

Tags: ruby, function, sass

If I have the following in my SASS:

```
$my-var: 1;
my_function();
```

And this as a function defined:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
    def my_function
    end
end
```

Is it possible to access the SASS variable `$my-var` within that function?

**Edit:**

My use case is that this function will be used in multiple stylesheets which all define their own value of `$my-var` as appropriate (for an id image URL path). This function will then be called in quite a few places within those stylesheets so I was hoping to avoid always passing in the variable to the function.

Comment: To my limited knowledge it's neither possible nor nice. Would you describe the real problem. I'm sure there are much better ways to accomplish that.

Comment: why are you not passing that variable as a parameter to that function? that would be obvious.

Comment: Added my use case to try and clarify my reasoning behind the question.

Comment: Your explanation even further makes it seem like you should pass the variable as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to drop down to the Ruby level for your function, you could use a Sass function as a wrapper around it like this:

```
$default-var: 1;
@function sass-function($var: $default-var) {
    @return ruby-function($var);
}
```

Comment: There is literally no reason to wrap it like that.  Just do `ruby-function($default-var);`.

Comment: @nzifnab I'm not disagreeing, but I interpreted the OP's question as wanting to take shortcuts when invoking the function.  The function in question might have 3 arguments where only 2 are *different* (eg. `foo(1, 1, $var)`, `foo(2, 3, $var)`, `foo(9, 2, $var)`, being able to abbreviate it to `foo(1, 1)` and `foo(2, 3)` is preferable).

Comment: Yes that's my reasoning the variable never changes throughout the individual SASS files (of which there are a lot) but it is different in each one. Also the function itself does need to be a ruby function, so this wrapper is probably my best bet. I'm not sure if I'll go this way though but a good option to have.